# How to set object value one by one in into text field using map function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I render textfile using the map function according to my array. Now I have an object and I need to set this object value into rendered out text field one by one. But I don't know the way to do this.

This is my object -

```js
const myObject={en: 'This is a good store', fr: "C'est un très bon magasin", ja: 'これは完全に良い店です'};
     {
        locals.map((item, index) => {
           return basicDetails(item, index, myObject);
         })
     }

const basicDetails = (item, index, myObject) => {
    return (
        <Grid>
             <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <CssTextField
                        value={myObject}
                        autoFocus
                        fullWidth
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Shop Tagline"
                    />
              </Grid>
    );
};
```

I just need to set my object value one by one into a textField.
I try to do this my result is [object Object].

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting [object Object] because the value you're passing to the `CssTextField` component is your entire object instead of one of its attributes.

I'm not sure what `locals` contains but my guess would be that you need to change this

```
locals.map((item, index) => {
 return basicDetails(item, index, myObject);
})
```

to this, assuming locals is an array that contains values such as `['en', 'fr', 'ja']`.

```
locals.map((item, index) => {
 return basicDetails(item, index, myObject[item]);
})
```